# Degree of the map $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \longmapsto \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R}$ $: X(z,t) = (z^2,t)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Consider the vector field $X : \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \longmapsto \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $X(z,t) = (z^2,t)$.

I'd like to prove that $X$ has only one zero of index $2$. This seems reasonable since $\mathbb{S}^{1} \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^{1}$ the power to the square has degree $2$ and basically I'm doing nothing on the second component. But I'm having trouble dealing with computation.

It's clear that $(0,0)$ is the only zero here, hence isolated. But I have to compute $\text{ind}_{X}((0,0))$ this is by definition the degree of the map from a ball centered in the zero, with any radius in this case to $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ in this case since we are in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (But it's not clear to me how I'm seeing $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ here as subset of $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R}$ ) which is $X(z,t) \longmapsto \frac{X(z,t)}{\lvert\lvert X(z,t)\rvert\rvert}$.

How to compute the degree of $X(z,t) \longmapsto \frac{X(z,t)}{\lvert\lvert X(z,t)\rvert\rvert}$ ? It's not even clear to me wether I should think this map as a composition or not, and try to guess who the regular values are.

The definition of degree I'm using is : Let $M$ be compact $N$ connected with dim$M=$dim$N$, both without boundary, orientable and oriented. Take $f : M \longmapsto N$ of class $C^{\infty}$ then deg($f$) := $\sum\limits_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} \text{sgn}df_x$ for $y \in \text{RegVal}(f)$.

The index of an isolated zero $p$ is defined as the pullback through a parametrization of the manifold of the index on an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ so I'm going to give this definition : $\text{ind}_X(p) := \text{deg}(f_{r})$, where $f_r : \partial B(p,r) \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ with $f_r(q) := \frac{X(q)}{\lvert \lvert X(q) \rvert \rvert}$ for every $r \in (0,\epsilon)$ given $\epsilon$ the radius of the ball where there are no other zeros.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: $M$ in your example is not compact so it's unclear to me how your definition of degree applies.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm looking for the index at $(0,0)$, so we have to restrict to $\mathbb{S}^{2}$, basically by definition of index given to me

Answer (score 1):

We can take $r=1$. Then your definition of the index is
$$ind_X(0)=deg(f_1)$$
where $f_1: S^2\to S^2$ is given by
$$f_1\left(se^{i\theta}, t\right) = \frac{\left(s^2e^{2i\theta}, t\right)}{\sqrt{s^4+t^2}},$$
where $s$ and $t$ are real positive numbers so that $s^2+t^2=1$. Now you must find a regular value to compute the degree of $f_1$. I suggest you use $(1,0)$. The inverse image are the two points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Is this clear so far? Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thanks, that's the point where I stopped during the resolution of the exercise, since the computation seemed too random. I didn't know wether there was a simpler way to solve or one just have calmly to do the calculus.

Comment: Well, if I was going to use this in something that was not homework, I would say $f_1$ is homotopic to $f$ given by $f(se^{i\theta}, t)= (se^{2i\theta}, t)$, so $f_1$ and $f$ has the same degree. Computing the degree of $f$ is of course less messy.

Comment: But calmly doing the work is often faster than insisting on being clever. It's also good to be able to. So if this was my homework, I would probably just have done the calculus.